# jQuery text() to grab "<" sign as part of the text

Tags: jquery, html

This node.js code receives html from the web and uses cheerio jQuery-like library to extract the text but it fails to grab the text after the "<" sign which is included as part of the text.
I am expecting the text "a)<14.5m left"
How can I get the whole text including the "<" sign? Thanks

```
$('td.displayValue').each(function() {
  const item = $(this).text().trim();
  console.log(item); // => a) but I am after "a) <14.5m left"
});
```

```html
<tr class="rowLight">
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="displayValue" valign="top">
    a) <14.5m left
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: can you create a demo?

Comment: did you try to convert your < to a &lt;

Comment: @progysm this is how I get the html file from the web. it will not be that easy to convert the right one since the html markup is full of those signs which belong to valid elements.

Comment: HTML is not valid if you have a number after a <

Comment: @progysm correct, the text I am after is not html but the string inside it. And the html file is received from the web, not created locally.

Comment: Are you doing that inside a nodejs script or using something like PhantomJS ? Because it can work with jquery + a desktop browser like firefox (I guess it use .textContent) : https://jsfiddle.net/bwt8rs15/1/ . Since the HTML code is invalid, it will really depend on the parser that you are using. I think that cheeriojs use htmlparser2 and use the attribute .data on each node to get the content. ( https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/blob/master/lib/ )

Comment: @progysm yes, node.js, added it to the post. thx.

Comment: Just FYI, the most 'correct' situation is that the less-than/greater-than signs are always part of the HTML markup, while any such symbols that are *intended* to be part of the document content should be expressed using the entity codes '&lt;' and '&gt;'.  The point is that, to have a less-than sign in the actual content, you should use '&lt;'.

Comment: @FredJ. https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/gctbg0jp/  if you hit f12 for the console you will see it logs the full text, not just a). Even if the text is separated onto 2 lines (as initially in the question) it logs all of it, just on 2 lines. So what is the problem? By the way you should use var, not const. Const indicates a constant.

Comment: https://github.com/fb55/htmlparser2/blob/master/lib/Tokenizer.js#L150  <-- I think this is where the htmlparser2 used by cheerio fail. It will always end the text data at the first '<' it find and doesn't check if the next chars are a valid tagname or not, like a desktop browser parser would do. If I was you, I would try to download the content, replace <1 by &lt;1,  parse it, then use cheerio on that string.

Comment: @progysm yes, that is what I am trying now. I hope that will fix it. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `.text()` , you can just simply use `.html()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by putting the content in `span` tags. You can choose to put the class on the span tags instead or a different class there instead. Either would work. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/bwt8rs15/)

```js
$('.displayValue').each(function() {
  var item = $(this).text().trim();
  console.log(item); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr class="rowLight">
  <td >
  <span class="displayValue"> a) < 14.5m left </span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: you don't need a span if you fix the < char with space around it.

Comment: Please note my question. This html is not built locally but downloaded from the web and have no control over how it is authored.

Comment: @progysm  https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/39268a5a/  fiddle without span with 'fixed' < character. Console logs nothing.

Comment: @RachelGallen This is because the selector doesn't work in jsfiddle if it's not inside a <table> tag

Comment: @progysm then it works either way https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/39268a5a/3/